# I cannot crawling with python

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I want to crawlling tag:p, class:txt
but I can't

weblink=https://school.iamservice.net/organization/18193/group/2079351

----------------code---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
import bs4, urllib.request

url="https://school.iamservice.net/organization/18193/group/2079351"


html=urllib.request.urlopen(url)

bsObj=bs4.BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")



txt=bsObj.findAll("p",{"class":"txt"})


print(txt)
```

Comment: So what happens when you run this code?  What results do you see vs. what you expected to see?

Comment: I got the same trouble with you when first time try beautiful soup. As Kundu's answer, not all website is html ready, many site using JS to render after loading (the rendering step is on your browser, that why you can see the content in, but if you load by beautiful soup, it's only a skeleton. Thus, use selenium to render the link as Kundu's answer. But selenium is a bit heavy for low-end computer and many APIs so try using Splash. Easiest way to install it is using docker container. https:// splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html#linux-docker

Answer (score 2):

Seems like `JavaScripts` render the page.You can use selenium webdriver and beautiful soup in that case.Hope this helps.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import bs4
import time
url="https://school.iamservice.net/organization/18193/group/2079351"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(4)
html=driver.page_source

bsObj=bs4.BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")

txt=bsObj.findAll("p",{"class":"txt"})

for t in txt:
    print(t.text)
```

Output:

```
찹쌀밥조갯살순두부찌개5.6.9.13.배추된장무침5.6.깍두기9.13.바나나닭볶음탕5.6.13.15.18.
찹쌀밥시금치된장국5.6.13.우엉땅콩조림4.5.6.13.돼지고기김치찜9.10.13.깍두기9.13.방울토마토12.
찰현미밥호박감자된장국5.6.13.깐쇼새우1.5.6.9.12.13.깍두기9.13.연두부+양념장5.6.13.콘치즈구이1.2.5.13.
보리밥감자국13.돼지갈비찜10.13.김구이13.배추김치9.13.파인애플
찹쌀밥오징어짬뽕국5.6.단무지탕수육1.2.5.6.10.11.12.13.배추김치9.13.자몽푸딩1.5.13.
찹쌀밥양상추샐러드&키위D(고)1.5.6.12.13.갈릭함박스테이크,소스(완,고)1.2.5.6.10.12.13.배추김치9.13.호상요구르트(포도)2.크림스프2.5.6.13.
찰현미밥콩나물국5.13.시금치나물떡갈비볶음2.5.6.10.13.깍두기9.13.청포도
미니햄버거1.2.5.6.10.12.13.바나나자두쥬스2.초코씨리얼+우유2.5.6.13.
찹쌀밥근대된장국5.6.13.무생채13.파닭5.6.12.13.배추김치9.13.
차조밥참나물무침5.6.돼지고기김치볶음9.10.13.감자크로켓1.2.5.6.10.12.13.깍두기9.13.쇠고기미역국5.6.16.18.
찹쌀밥도라지오이생채5.6.13.고등어구이2.5.6.7.13.총각김치9.13.망고쥬스유부김치국5.9.13.
생선커틀렛1.2.5.6.13.포도(캠벨)식혜단호박스프2.5.6.13.모닝빵1.2.5.6.13.
치킨마요덮밥1.5.6.13.감자국13.치커리사과샐러드5.6.13.총각김치9.13.방울토마토12.
찹쌀밥청국장찌개5.9.10.13.깻잎찜5.6.돼지불고기5.6.10.13.총각김치9.13.
검정콩밥5.조랭이떡국1.5.6.13.메추리알돈육장조림1.5.6.10.13.청포묵김무침5.6.13.배추김치9.13.짜먹는 요구르트2.
찹쌀밥북어콩나물국1.5.6.13.배추된장무침5.6.닭갈비5.6.13.깍두기9.13.바나나
찹쌀밥콩비지찌개5.9.10.13.취나물볶음5.6.13.순대채소볶음5.6.10.13.깍두기9.13.
찹쌀밥어묵무국1.5.6.13.잡채5.6.8.10.13.16.오징어바튀김1.5.6.12.13.배추김치9.13.
웨지감자2.12.13.오렌지프렌치토스트1.2.5.6.10.12.13.아몬드씨리얼+우유2.5.6.13.
혼합곡밥5.열무된장국5.6.13.훈제오리1.5.13.부추겉절이13.배추김치9.13.쌈무
```